All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABIs issue, while generating .aab file in android
Does dynamic feature module require same architectures to be mentioned as it is mentioned in base module ?
I am trying to make zoom_6.2.3.24722.aar version as a dynamic feature module in my project. In my project i have Module A which has all architectures (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64) support, and zoom_6.2.3.24722.aar has only two architectures (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a) support based on their documentation , while generating .aab file i am getting below error.
All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABIs, but module ‘base’ supports ‘[ARM64_V8A, ARMEABI_V7A, X86, X86_64]’ and module ‘zoomISV’ supports ‘[ARM64_V8A, ARMEABI_V7A]’
Any solution, leads are appreciated.
What i have tried,

I tried to manually include X86 and X86_64 in zoom build.gradle. - did not worked
I tried to unzip the zoom aar file and added X_86 and X_86_64 manually and kept sample .so files inside them and generated .aar file again - did not worked

What i am expecting,
Since zoom feature is optional for my project, it should be able to build without having the base module configuration as a dependency, my app should target all the app architecture, just because for zoom i can not exclude X86 and X86_64 support for my app.
